# How to Encrypt String with special characters in android?

Tags: android, javax.crypto

I need to encrypt the username and password and encode them and send it via SOAP header.
I used DES algorithm to encrypt the plainText `

```
String key = "qwer1234qwetr123wqw";
        String x = "sadgsagd:%%^%ghsagdh";
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[1024];
        byte[] plaintext = x.getBytes();
        byte[] tdesKeyData = key.getBytes();

    Cipher c3des = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec myKey = new SecretKeySpec(tdesKeyData, "DESede");
    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);

    c3des.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey, ivspec);
    byte[] cipherText = c3des.doFinal(plaintext);
    int hash = Base64.encode(cipherText).hashCode();

    return Base64.encode(cipherText);`
```

At runtime i am getting an Exception:

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given

Comment: what's your size of byte buffer?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using byte buffer of `64`,i probably is too long change it to `32`,
  or  use the `length` of `file` like this `byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)new File("data").length()];`

my problem get solved after doing this..